# Turning off static type checking in c++ for a particular method call

Tags: c++

I'm using class templates. I have a method that checks to see if it's argument type is a fundamental type (like "int") or an instance of an object (using typeid). If it is an object I want to call a method on that instance. My problem is that the compiler complains when the type variable is bound to "int".

Is there a way to force the check to be performed at run-time??

I'm using g++ on OS X Lion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there isn't. Code and the actual problem you're trying to solve, please, not a broken solution you think is best.

Comment: Looks like you got a bad case of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Could you show us how the code looks like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a template specialization to achieve this, not `typeid`. SFINAE can help you write one for all fundamental types faster, I believe.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand all the ins and outs of SFINAE, but I did get it work to solve my problem. Interesting idiom. Thanks again.